# Change a background image only if the new background image exits

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<style>
    .image {
        width: 136px;
        height: 23px;
        background-color: red;
        background-image: url(placeholder.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: auto 100%;
    }

    .image.real {
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>
<div id="image" class="image"></div>
```

In the above layout, I would like to obtain another image from a URL and, after obtaining the image, add another class to the div and set its background image URL to this new URL. Something like:

```
var image = document.getElementById('image');
image.className += ' real';
image.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://www.example.com/real.png)';
```

However, the problem appears when the image does not exist. How can I do something like this and add the `real` class name and change the URL only if the image exists, but not otherwise?

I was thinking of making an AJAX request to see if it's successful, then set the class name and URL if so, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/BHr8D/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here is an example using native JavaScript

You need to check to see if the image exists (can be loaded) before applying it as a background.

This problem was addressed previously by:

[javascript check image existence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609036/javascript-check-image-existence)

which presents a native JavaScript method for checking if an image exists.

The code might look like the following:

```
var image = document.getElementById('image');
image.src = "http://www.example.com/real.png";

image.onerror = function( ) {
    /* do some appropriate action... */
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
img.onload = function( ) {
    image.className += ' real';
    image.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://www.example.com/real.png)';
}
```

### Comment

I am not sure if the server overhead for loading  the image is less than that associated with making an AJAX request.  Perhaps someone else can comment.

Answer (score 1):

### Here is an example using jQuery

I think that you should create a new image element, attach it to DOM and listen for events:

```
var image = $('<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg/300px-Hopetoun_falls.jpg" />');
image.on("load", function() {
    // add the class here
    invisibleContainer.remove();
    console.log("loaded");
});
image.on("error", function() {
    // do something if the image is missing
    console.log("image is missing");
});
var invisibleContainer = $('<div></div>');
invisibleContainer.css("display", "none");
$('body').append(invisibleContainer);
```

JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qkXZ4/